# How do I email a copied doc from a google form?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working with 3 documents:

- [This google form][1]
- [This spreadsheet of form responses][2]
- [This google doc template][3]

When someone submits the form, I would like the following workflow automated:

1. The template is copied into this folder with some items copied from the form into the new copied doc. (My script is currently functioning and getting that done)
2. The person who submits the form is owner of the new document & receives an email alert for their new document (Cannot figure this part out.  I have tried the addEditor method, but I am getting an error)
3. The URL of the new document copy is added to column L of the form responses spreadsheet so the new documents are indexed and easily accessible.

Here is the script I am using:

```
    function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var email = e.values[1];
  var firstName = e.values[2];
  var lastName = e.values[3];
  var crossroadsEmail = e.values[4];
  const building = e.values[5];
  var grade = e.values[6];
  var subject = e.values[7];
  var course = e.values[8];
  var title = e.values[9];
  var length = e.values[10];
  
  
  //define variables in both sheets
  var formresponses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var lastrowformresponses = formresponses.getLastRow();
  var formresponsesrange = formresponses.getRange(1, 1, lastrowformresponses, 12);
  
  //file is the template file, and you get it by ID
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1GKmUZCN8Maq74UWBFNLscd1xh1GKDMvD2tpZWhI9Ou8'); 
  
  //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
  //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1q9nfUtJ-iI00etxLSHJKsBJ7cQR-7brC')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(subject + ',' + grade + ',' + title , folder); 
  
  //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
  body.replaceText('{{First Name}}', firstName); 
  body.replaceText('{{Last Name}}', lastName);  
  body.replaceText('{{Title of Unit}}', title); 
  body.replaceText('{{Subject}}', subject); 
  body.replaceText('{{Grade}}', grade);  
  body.replaceText('{{Name of Course}}', course); 
  body.replaceText('{{Length of Unit}}', length);  
  
  // we save and close the document to persist our changes
  var url = doc.getUrl();
  doc.saveAndClose();
  
  //We add the teacher as the editor
  var editorEmail = formresponsesrange.getCell(lastrowformresponses, 2);
  DocumentApp.openByUrl(url).addEditor(editorEmail);
    
  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

You would need to add `getValue();` for your variable editorEmail since `getCell()` only references the cell range and not the value within the cell.

It should look something like this:

```
     var editorEmail = formresponsesrange.getCell(lastrowformresponses, 2).getValue();
     DocumentApp.openByUrl(url).addEditor(editorEmail);
```

**Suggestion:**

You can remove these lines of code `var url = doc.getUrl();` and `doc.saveAndClose();` since `openById(copy.getId())` opens the document and saves whatever changes was made on the document that was opened.

You can also remove this: `var formresponsesrange = formresponses.getRange(1, 1, lastrowformresponses, 12);` since we don't need to define the range of the entire responses sheet.

The final output should look like this:

```
        function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
      //e.values is an array of form values
      var timestamp = e.values[0];
      var email = e.values[1];
      var firstName = e.values[2];
      var lastName = e.values[3];
      var crossroadsEmail = e.values[4];
      const building = e.values[5];
      var grade = e.values[6];
      var subject = e.values[7];
      var course = e.values[8];
      var title = e.values[9];
      var length = e.values[10];
      
      
      //define variables in both sheets
      var formresponses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var lastrowformresponses = formresponses.getLastRow();
      
      //file is the template file, and you get it by ID
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1rBi_L1Y5KV0ncf3M9SmnTHRP26Vw8ipU2f7X6bi9QhE'); 
      
      //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
      //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1f-18Lxaa2OU1dS-JdxTRKekgLQae0MD8')
      var copy = file.makeCopy(subject + ',' + grade + ',' + title , folder); 
      
      //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
      
      //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
      var body = doc.getBody(); 
      var url = doc.getUrl();

      //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
      body.replaceText('{{First Name}}', firstName); 
      body.replaceText('{{Last Name}}', lastName);  
      body.replaceText('{{Title of Unit}}', title); 
      body.replaceText('{{Subject}}', subject); 
      body.replaceText('{{Grade}}', grade);  
      body.replaceText('{{Name of Course}}', course); 
      body.replaceText('{{Length of Unit}}', length);  
      
      //We add the teacher as the editor
      var editorEmail = formresponses.getRange(lastrowformresponses, 2).getValue();
      DocumentApp.openById(doc.getId()).addEditor(editorEmail);
      MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: editorEmail,
      subject: "Test Email",
      htmlBody: url
      })
      }
```

**EDIT**

Added the script and I returned `var url = doc.getUrl();` from your original code:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: editorEmail,
    subject: "Test Email",
    htmlBody: url

  })
```

You can check out this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) for more options to modify or change the contents of the email that was sent.

NOTE: You would need to run the script for the first time on the script editor so that it will prompt the authentication to access the Gmail Service.

Comment: Thank you, Diego!  Unfortunately, I am still not receiving an email notification that the doc has been created.  I am stumped.

Comment: Updated my answer above @AllisonBucklew